# Show and Hide AppBar on Screen Tap in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

[image] [image]

I want like the Above images.
I want to create an app that will Hide and Show the AppBar and Bottom bar of the app on-screen tap.

so I tried It by SetState method and worked great but The Problem is with this only

When AppBar Hides the App Content Goes Up but I want that My Content should be fixed.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool _showAppBar = true;
  bool _showBottomBar = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: _showAppBar ? AppBar(title: Text('My App')) : null,
      bottomNavigationBar: _showBottomBar ? BottomNavigationBar(items: [
        BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home), label: 'Home'),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.search), label: 'Search'),
      ]) : null,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            setState(() {
              _showAppBar = !_showAppBar;
              _showBottomBar = !_showBottomBar;
            });
          },
          child: Image.network('https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/funny-monkey-animal-cartoon-sticker_1308-75307.jpg?w=2000'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Wrap your `Image.network` with `Center`

Comment: Yeah But I did not want center widget. I want the content on the top

Answer (score 1):

If You click on Widget the appbar is hide your appbar is hide successfully but you return it null please change this below hope its help to you.

```
appBar: _showAppBar ? AppBar(title: Text('My App')) : AppBar(backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,),
```

Full Code:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool _showAppBar = true;
  bool _showBottomBar = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: _showAppBar ? AppBar(title: Text('My App')) : AppBar(backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,),
      bottomNavigationBar: _showBottomBar ? BottomNavigationBar(items: [
        BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home), label: 'Home'),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.search), label: 'Search'),
      ]) : null,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            setState(() {
              _showAppBar = !_showAppBar;
              _showBottomBar = !_showBottomBar;
            });
          },
          child: Image.network('https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/funny-monkey-animal-cartoon-sticker_1308-75307.jpg?w=2000'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks For your reply sir, But I want my image should be there when AppBar is Hide. Just Like Inshorts or Way2News

Comment: Can't understand explain in brief, have you try my answer?

Comment: I have edited my question. please take a look

Comment: Ok got it you want when click the image or scroll the page then appbar is move up?

Comment: Yes. I want like that

Comment: Use [SliverAppBar](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SliverAppBar-class.html) Widget

Answer (score 0):

You can use preferred size widget instead of appbar as below code and then you can change height as per your use

```
appBar:_showAppBar 
? PreferredSize(
  preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(100),
  child: Container(color: Colors.red) 
: PreferredSize(
  preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(100),
  child: Container(color: Colors.transparent),
),
```

Comment: I want Inshorts like AppBar, AppBar can Caver the Image but no blank space should be there.

Comment: Please add your current and expected output image

Comment: I have edited my question. please take a look

Comment: Is this your answer? please check [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54680745/how-do-i-make-the-appbar-slide-from-top-and-overlay-the-screen-content-just-lik)

Comment: Yes I want the same features

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your whole `body` with `Padding` and toggle it when you hide the `appBar` and `bottomNavigationBar` like so:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool _showAppBar = true;
  bool _showBottomBar = true;

  double appBarHeight = 56.0; // default appBar height

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: _showAppBar ? AppBar(title: Text('My App')) : null,
      bottomNavigationBar: _showBottomBar
          ? BottomNavigationBar(items: [
              BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home), label: 'Home'),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.search), label: 'Search'),
            ])
          : null,
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: _showAppBar ? 0 : appBarHeight),
        child: SafeArea(
          child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                _showAppBar = !_showAppBar;
                _showBottomBar = !_showBottomBar;
              });
            },
            child: Image.network(
                'https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/funny-monkey-animal-cartoon-sticker_1308-75307.jpg?w=2000'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I have edited my question. please take a look

Comment: I think that you are trying to achieve something like `SliverAppBar` behaviour. If so, take a look at this link --> https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-add-sliverappbar-to-your-flutter-app/